# Uploading real time data on dynamodb using lambda function

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, real-time, amazon-kinesis, data-stream

we're trying to upload real-time data using a kinesis data generator on aws-dynamodb using the lambda function. Our code works fine while running the test cases but fails to upload data in production.
Here is our lambda function :

```
import boto3
import json
import base64

def lambda_handler(event, context):
   dynamo_db = boto3.resource('dynamodb')
   table = dynamo_db.Table('dyno-table')
   try:
      data = [record.get('kinesis').get('data') for record in event['Records']]
    
      for record in data:
         recordeddata = base64.b64decode(record).decode("utf-8")
         decoded_data_dic = json.loads(recordeddata)
         with table.batch_writer() as batch_writer:
            batch_writer.put_item(Item=decoded_data_dic)
      return data
    except Exception as e:
      return str(e)
```

And here is sample of our json data sent from kinesis.

```
{
"Records": [
{
  "kinesis": {
    "kinesisSchemaVersion": "1.0",
    "partitionKey": "4159727726",
    "sequenceNumber": "49639282004144167688658152268735854270994120426068639794",
    "data": "eyJmaXJzdE5hbWUiOiJBbnRvbmV0dGUiLCJsYXN0TmFtZSI6IlRoaWVsIiwiaWQiOjYsImlwIjoiMTAwLjIyNy4zOC4yMTMiLH0K",
    "approximateArrivalTimestamp": 1680243715.662
  },
  "eventSource": "aws:kinesis",
  "eventVersion": "1.0",
  "eventID": "shardId-000000000003:49639282004144167688658152268735854270994120426068639794",
  "eventName": "aws:kinesis:record",
  "invokeIdentityArn": "arn:aws:iam::777050133147:role/AvaniK-LambdaRole",
  "awsRegion": "ap-northeast-1",
  "eventSourceARN": "arn:aws:kinesis:ap-northeast-1:777050133147:stream/DeepakR-datastream"
}
]
}
```

and here is data schema:

```
{
  "firstName":"{{name.firstName}}",
  "lastName":"{{name.lastName}}",
  "id":{{random.number(70)}},
  "ip":"{{internet.ip}}",
  }
```

Comment: Are you running your tests and the productive system on the same AWS Account?

Answer (score 1):

You issue is due to the fact you are sending malformed JSON in your Kinesis  base64 encoded payload:

`{"firstName":"Antonette","lastName":"Thiel","id":6,"ip":"100.227.38.213",}`

This causes your `json.loads()` function to fail:

```
Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes: line 1 column 74 (char 73)
```

You need to provide valid JSON for it to work.